# Model inheritance in Laravel without plugins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What i am trying to achieve is a *base* model that has certain fields and *sub* models that have even more custom fields. I found some hacky solutions that used a field in the table to define the subtype, but that does not feel right.

So here is an example of what i need:
I have a model **Pet** that has common fields like *name*, *age*, *gender*. However, i do not wanna use this model directly (so it is okay if it is e.g. *abstract*).

Then i have sub models like for example:

- **Bird** that has the field *lengthOfWings*
- **Spider** that has *numberOfEyes*
- **Dog** that has *breed*

How can this be done cleanly?

Comment: I think the closest "laravel" way of doing this is using polymorphic realtions

Answer (score 0):

If your model Pet extends laravel's model class, you can't define it abstract, and i don't think you want to implement it from scratch

If i understand right, the cleanest way i could think of would be

```
Pet Model
    +--------+----------+--------------------+
    |     id | name     | oder_general_field |
    +--------+----------+--------------------+
    |      1 |      dog |               value|
    |      2 |      cat |               value|
    |      3 |     bird |               value|
    +--------+----------+--------------------+

Subtype model

    +------------+----------+
    | subtype_id | name     |
    +------------+----------+
    |      1     |mammal    |
    |      2     |not_mammal|
    +------------+----------+


  Mammal model

  +---+--------+----------+------------+
  |id | pet_id | field1   | field2     |
  +---+--------+----------+------------+
  | 1 |      1 |    value |       value|
  | 2 |      2 |    value |       value|
  +---+--------+----------+------------+

  Not_Mammal model

   +----+--------+----------+------------+
   | id | pet_id | field1   | field2     |
   +----+--------+----------+------------+
   | 1  |      3 |    value |       value|
   +----+--------+----------+------------+
```

The subtype model here is not used in the relationship, but i would recommend to keep it, and whenever you add a new model add it's name there too, if you will have like 100 submodels trust me it will help you

Then you will have to define the relationships between models

```
Class Mammal Extends Model{
     public function pet(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pet');
     }
} 

Class Not_Mammal Extends Model{
     public function pet(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pet');
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but forget the mammal stuff. I actually wanted a "class bird", "class spider" as subclasses of pet. Then i can have e.g. 2 dogs Balu (breed shepard) and Roger (breed bulldog)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class animal.

ex:

class animal extends Model

{

//some statement here

}

Then create another class or model

class Dog extends Animal
{

// statement here

}

i hope this helps

Comment: your class Animal now extends the Model class of the laravel